# Two is company, three's a crowd

Tags: riddle, knowledge, cryptic-clues

> Should the northern wall serve beer
>   The first of me and the last of a beloved voice
>   Dark and flat on high
>   A popular Dino and hard metal senator
>   The beginning of a life without meaning and a song of a nation
>   Lloyd Banks and change minus one, with a Y chromosome

All of the lines/clues are related to a single thing.

What is that thing?

Edit: Here are some more lines that might help, but mostly for more fun:

> I see the end ahead and lateral scuttling
>   If Isaac Newton and Samuel Colt had a child, maybe

Comment: Looks like you've got everyone stumped

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil I will add a clue if no one has figured it out or made a good attempt by tomorrow

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the answer is

> Half-Life

Should the northern wall serve beer

> Wallace Breen (Wall N + ace + beer, all mixed up) 
>  **or** Crowbar (as revealed by Gordon Allocman)

The first of me and the last of a beloved voice

> Gordon Freeman (First part of the asker's username, **Gordon** Allocman, plus last of Morgan **Freeman**, a beloved voice, thanks to Patrick Roberts)

Dark and flat on high

> Black Mesa

A popular Dino and hard metal senator

> Barney Calhoun (**Barney** the dinosaur + John C. **Calhoun**, nicknamed the "cast-iron man")

The beginning of a life without meaning and a song of a nation

> Nihilanth (First parts of **Nihil**istic + **anth**em)

Lloyd Banks and change minus one, with a Y chromosome

> G-man (Thanks to Dan Russell in first answer, **G**-unit minus unit plus **man**)

I see the end ahead and lateral scuttling

> Headcrab (a**head** + crab)

If Isaac Newton and Samuel Colt had a child, maybe

> Gravity Gun (thanks to question_asker)

All of them

> Appear in the series of games Half-Life

Two is company, three's a crowd

> Possible reference to the much publicised delay of the third game. Thanks to commenters gannolloy and question_asker for bringing this up.

Comment: Does the title relate at all to that show?

Comment: @gannolloy insofar as people have been clamoring for a third and it hasn't come

Comment: The last one is ROT13(tenivgl tha)

Comment: This looks like it must be right, though I would've had no chance, not being familiar with the series.  Shouldn't this question have a `knowledge` tag at least?

Comment: Yup, that is it, your interpretation of the first clue is not what I had intended but it ends up working! I didn't tag this video games because I thought it would be too big of a clue

Comment: In case anyone is curious, the first clue was meant to be ROT13 (Pebjone (Abegurea jnyy -> pebjf sebz Tnzr bs Guebarf, freir orre -> gur vpbavp jrncba bs gur tnzr))

Comment: @Gordon Allocman Yes, I was curious. Thank you for the answer, I may put it in alongside mine if that's okay. Great puzzle, by the way!

Comment: @DanRussell that's a good point I added the knowledge tag for future viewers

Answer (score 4):

Possible partial answer to get the ball rolling:

> Last line:
>  "Lloyd Banks and change" (50-cent) make up G-unit
>  "Minus one" could mean take away "unit" leaving G
>  "Y-chromosome" implies male, so G-male or **Gmail** or **G-man** (related to OP, Gordon Allocman? G-man!)

Perhaps answers are:

> Mail providers or Google services

Comment: I may have gotten the second one: [SPOILER](http://pastebin.com/rVNY84XJ), though I'm not sure about the connection...

Comment: @paste Post as answer. It helps others solve the puzzle. Nice one, by the way.

Comment: You are very close with that clue, but you missed the mark with your conclusion

Comment: @paste unfortunately that is not the correct interpretation of the second line, good attempt though!

Comment: The first of me [(G)ordon] and the last of a beloved voice [Morgan Free(man)] => (male) = Gmail?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I think you might be missing the forest for the trees there